# Entity Framework [ForeignKey]

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Lendo um tutorial sobre entity framework, me deparei com um exemplo um tanto estranho para mim. Esse exemplo é sobre a DataAnnotation `[ForeignKey]`

```
public class Student
{
    public Student()
    { 

    }
    public int StudentID { get; set; }
    public string StudentName { get; set; }

    //Foreign key for Standard
    public int StandardId { get; set; }

    public Standard Standard { get; set; }
}

public class Standard
{
    public Standard()
    { 

    }
    public int StandardId { get; set; }
    public string StandardName { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Student> Students { get; set; }

    }
```

Em um cenário sem ORM, ou seja, lidando diretamente com ADO.net, eu não vejo sentido que `Student` tenha um atributo referente ao `Id` do `Standard`, pois `Student` já possui uma referência para `Standard`, onde essa referência já possui o `Id`.
Por que o EF trabalha dessa forma?
Ao meu ver parece redundante.

Comment: Não está claro o que `[ForeignKey]` tem a ver com a pergunta. Se acha que tem redundância, precisa analisar o contexto. Pode ser que seja redundante mesmo, mas foi uma decisão de quem fez este código. Mas pode ser que não tenha. Está sem contexto.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Matheus, acredito que você não está levando em conta uma coisa: `LazyLoad`.

Defido ao LazyLoad, ao se buscar um `Student`, apenas os dados do `Student` são recuperados do Banco, apenas se você vier à acessar a propriedade de Navegação `Standard` que o EF vai buscar os seus dados.

Para fazer este carregamento preguiçoso, é necessario que a propriedade de navegação tenha o modificador `virtual`, com isto o EF consegue modificar o comportamento do mesmo.

Observe o mapeamento das suas entidades usando `Code First`, talvez você consiga notar isto melhor.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.Data.Entity;

public partial class Contexto : DbContext
{
    public Contexto() : base("name=Contexto")
    {
    }

    public virtual DbSet<Standard> Standards { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Student> Students { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Standard>().Property(e => e.Name).IsUnicode(false);
        modelBuilder.Entity<Standard>().HasMany(e => e.Students).WithRequired(e => e.Standard).WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
        modelBuilder.Entity<Student>().Property(e => e.Name).IsUnicode(false);
    }
}

[Table("Student")]
public partial class Student
{
    public int StudentID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int StandardID { get; set; }

    public virtual Standard Standard { get; set; }
}

[Table("Standard")]
public partial class Standard
{
    public Standard()
    {
        Students = new HashSet<Student>();
    }

    public int StandardID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Student> Students { get; set; }
}
```

Se você criar uma nova entidade `Student`, e setar um valor para `StandardID` que já exista no banco de dados, e apos isto tentar acessar a propriedade `Standard` o EF vai buscar os dados da Entidade `Standard` no Banco de Dados.

Porém se você não acessar a propriedade de navegação e apenas setar o Valor da propriedade `StandardID`, a consulta adicional não será realizada, porém caso tente salvar a entidade `Student`, o EF não terá problemas em faze-lo.

Note que nem sempre é necessario acessar uma propriedade de navegação, as vezes conhecer apenas o ID da mesma já é o suficiente.

Comment: O NHibernate não usa essa "chave estrangeira" na classe e faz lazyload muito bem. Acho que a equipe do EF deu mole mesmo. O Nhibernate faz lazy load carregando uma classe proxy com apenas o identificador preenchido e quando precisa de mais informações vai ao BD. e em vez de setar StandardID com o id nós setamos a própria variável Standard com session.load(id) que ele carrega a classe proxy sem ir ao BD, confiando que o ID existe.

Comment: Grato pelo esclarecimento.
Vendo outros exemplos me deparei com outra situação estranha.
Existe duas classes `Student` e `Address`. Pela lógica UML, um `Student` tem um `Address`, ou seja, na classe `Student` deve haver uma propriedade de navegação para `Address`. Mas no exemplo que estou vendo, `Student` tem um objeto de navegação para `Address` e `Address` tb tem um atributo de navegação para `Student`.
Isso não faz muito sentido para mim pois é um `Student` é que tem um `Address` e não o contrário.

Comment: @MatheusSaraiva, no EF você também pode `context.Standards.Find(id)`deve ser algo semelhante ao seu exemplo no NHibernate, e da mesma forma que o NHibernate, o EF precisa que a propriedade de navegação seja virtual para pode criar o proxy, assim fazendo o LazyLoad. E não existe esta de carregar a classe proxy sem ir ao banco, você pode até ligar o profile para ver as consultas sendo executadas

Comment: Quanto ao fator do Estudante possuir um Endereço e não o inverso, você pode entender isto como uma regra de negocio, e não como uma limitação tecnológica, afinal podemos ter relacionamentos 1:1 bidirecional, em todo caso não vejo problema em o Studant ser acessivel apartir do Adress, mas se preferir, você pode não fazer este mapeamento.

Comment: Quanto a comparar o NHibernate com o Entity Framework, o EF tem suporte a operações assincronas, tem um suporte melhor ao linq, eu que estou acostumado com EF e agora trabalho com NHibernate, sempre fico puto quando aparece uma Exception `OperationNotSupported`.

Answer (score 3):

[Como dito nos comentários pelo @Maniero](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/126999/entity-framework-foreignkey#comment264766_126999), fica difícil julgar se está correto ou não o mapeamento sem o contexto, o que pode ser feito é analisar e explicar o que o código está fazendo.

Não está errado este mapeamento:

```
public class Student
{
    public Student()
    { 

    }
    public int StudentID { get; set; }
    public string StudentName { get; set; }

    //Não necessida da anotação [ForeignKey]
    public int StandardId { get; set; }

    public Standard Standard { get; set; }
}

public class Standard
{
    public Standard()
    { 

    }
    public int StandardId { get; set; }
    public string StandardName { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Student> Students { get; set; }

    }
```

No código acima, temos um mapeamento de **1:N**, onde um `Standard` possui vários `Students` , onde a propriedade `StandardId` é a **foreing key** do modelo `Student`. Está correto, se o objetivo for esse. Utilizando o Entity Framework, não é necessário utilizar a anotação `[ForeignKey]`, pois o nome da *foreing key* é o nome da propriedade de navegação com o prefixo `id`, ou seja, `StandardId` (Standard + Id).

Em contra partida, o modelo `Standard` possui uma coleção de `Students`, onde o mesmo não necessita de ter uma **foreing key** para `Students`, caracterizando a ligação de **1:N**.

Answer (score -1):

É muito simples. O Entity Framework irá, de qualquer forma, criar esse StandardId na base de dados. O que acontece é, você quer ou não ter o controle da criação desta coluna?

Outra, você poderá realizar consultas na tabela de `Student` sem precisar ir até a tabela de `Standard`. Exemplo: Vc precisa selecionar todos os `Student` do `Standard` **10**.

```
_context.Students
    .Where(student => student.StandardId == 10)
    .ToList(); // Acessa apenas a entidade Student
// SELECT * FROM Student WHERE StandardId = 10
```

Se você deixa **implícito** o `StandardId`, teria que fazer:

```
_contexto.Students
    .Where(student => student.Standard.Id == 10)
    .ToList(); // Acessa entidades Student e Standard
// SELECT Student.* FROM Student
//   JOIN Standard ON Standard.Id = Student.StandardId
//  WHERE Standard.Id = 10
```

Comment: `_context.Students.Where(student => student.StandardId == 10)` e `_contexto.Students.Where(student => student.Standard.Id == 10)` não vão executar nenhuma consulta, vão gerar uma `Expression Tree`, porém ao executar o ToList, esta `Expression Tree` é convertida para um `comando SQL`, e no caso acima, os dois comandos gerão a mesma consulta, portanto são equivalentes, então não estou vendo o seu ponto.

Comment: @TobyMosque, no exemplo eu tinha já colocado o `.ToList()`. Editei a resposta afim de mostrar as queries que o EntityFramework irá criar.

Comment: @ThiafoLunardi, esperimentou fazer um `var query1 = (_context.Students.Where(student => student.StandardId == 10)).ToString()` e `var query 2= (_context.Students.Where(student => student.Standard.Id == 10)).ToString()`? se o fizer verá que `query1` é igual a `query2`, algo semelhante à `SELECT 
    [Extent1].[StudentID] AS [StudentID], 
    [Extent1].[Name] AS [Name], 
    [Extent1].[StandardID] AS [StandardID]
FROM [dbo].[Student] AS [Extent1]
WHERE 10 = [Extent1].[StandardID]`

Comment: @TobyMosque, a `query2` ficará `SELECT [Extent1].[StudentID] AS [StudentID], [Extent1].[Name] AS [Name], [Extent1].[StandardID] AS [StandardID] FROM [dbo].[Student] AS [Extent1], [dbo].[Standard] AS [Extent2] WHERE [Extend2].[ID] = [Extent1].[StandardID] AND 10 = [Extent1].[StandardID]`

Comment: não sei qual versão do `EF` esta usando, mas eu estou utilizando o `EF 6.1.3` e no meu caso o `query1` é igual a `query2`, em ambos os casos não foi realizado o `JOIN` com `Standard`